# Getting undefined 'image' errors when using paperclip for image upload?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I am trying to use paperclip to show a user's image in the posts index, but all I get is a "missing" link in its place.

I am using Devise for authentication.  And paperclip for image upload.  Which is frustrating since it works some of the time for me, but occaisonaly brings me annoying errors like this.  Thanks for the help, I've been stuck here a couple days now.

Here is my posts index: (error is thrown on 8th line)

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <ul>
    <li>
   <div class="well well-large">
   <div class="media">
    <a class="pull-left" href="#">
     <%= image_tag current_user.image.url(:thumb) %>
    </a>
    <div class="media-body">
     <h4 class="media-heading"><%= post.title %></h4>
      <%= post.content %>

<!-- Nested media object -->
      <div class="media">

      </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
<% end %>
   </li>
```

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :posts
    has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :thumb => "100x100>" },
          :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"

validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

Post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
end
```

Here are my post_params from my posts controller:

```
private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content)
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite apparent from error that you're getting. Look at the line:

```
<a class="pull-left" href="#">
  <%= image_tag current_user.image.url(:thumb) %>
</a>
```

Here your `current_user` in `nil`, and hence you get:

> undefined method `image' for nil:NilClass

Which means that you're requesting this method and loading this view when the user isn't logged in i.e. no user session has been made. Please put a check in your `PostsController`: `before_filter :authenticate_user!` or try to sign in before you access `PostsController`'s index method.

Comment: Thank you very much, I wish everyone answered like that, it helped me understand everything at a deeper level.  I no longer get an error, but instead of an image showing, it is just a "missing link", and I made sure to upload an image.

Comment: @joesmith: I'm glad that your problem is solved. If answer helps you then please accept it by clicking on the check mark on the left side of the answer so others can use it for reference (if they run into same issue in future). Thanks.

Comment: @JoeSmith: Why did you remove error you mentioned from your post and changed it as if the problem never existed, do you know that your update makes the answer not so useful and irrelevant now?? You have 'missing' link issue because the image path isn't being set properly. i.e. the path which is being saved in table can not resolve the actual file location. I hope it helps.

Comment: I was updating the question with its current state of information in hope of getting an answer that got the image upload working completely.  And yes that helps, where is it not being set properly in the view?

Comment: @JoeSmith: Please ask another question if it's a new issue. What I meant by not setting properly is that the data in: `current_user.image.url(:thumb)` must not be having the actual path where the image resides on the filesystem. :)